# Symmetric difference, characteristic function, Lebesgue norm

Tags: lebesgue-measure, characteristic-functions

I have a question about the following equality:

The following paragraph is clear:

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset and $A \subset \Omega$ a subset with finite measure. Then there exists a set B, which is a finite, disjoint union of boxes, such that, for $\epsilon>0$ and $\lambda$ being the Lebesgue measure it follows, that $\lambda(A\Delta B)<\epsilon$.

Next, let $1\leq p < \infty$,$~$ $A,B\subset \Omega$ be as above and consider the characteristic functions $\chi_A$ and $\chi_B$. Then the Lebesgue norm  $||\chi_A - \chi_B||_p^p=\lambda(A\Delta B)<\epsilon^p$.

How does the last equality follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$ \Vert \chi_A - \chi_B \Vert_p^p = \Vert \chi_{A \Delta B} \Vert_p^p = \int \vert \chi_{A\Delta B} \vert^p \ d\lambda = \int \vert \chi_{A\Delta B}\vert \ d\lambda = \lambda(A\Delta B) < \varepsilon. $$
The additional power $p$ in what you wrote seems to be wrong.

**Added:** Using the definition of characteristic function we get
$$ \vert \chi_A(x) - \chi_B(x)\vert = \begin{cases} \vert 0 - 0\vert,& x\in (A\cup B)^c,\\ \vert 1-1 \vert ,& x\in A \cap B,\\
\vert 1-0 \vert ,& x\in A\setminus B, \\
\vert 0 - 1 \vert,& x\in B \setminus A, 
\end{cases}
= \begin{cases}
1,& x\in (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)\\
0,& x\notin (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A).
\end{cases} $$ 
However, we have $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)= A\Delta B$ and thus we get
$$ \vert \chi_A(x) - \chi_B(x)\vert = \vert \chi_{A\Delta B}(x) \vert. $$

Comment: Thank you. When I try to validate the first equality, I get $|\chi_{A\Delta B}| = |\chi_A - \chi_B|^2$. How to make $|\chi_A - \chi_B|$ out of that?

Comment: @JtSpKg Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!