# How do we conclude that $ \chi_D(x)=\chi_{D+y}(x). \, a.e. $?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $D$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and $y\in \mathbb{R}$. If we assume that the Lebesgue measure $m(D\Delta(D+y))=0$. Here $A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$. How do we conclude that
$$
\chi_D(x)=\chi_{D+y}(x).  \, a.e.
$$

---

I try to rewrite it as integral
$$
0=m(D\Delta(D+y))=\int_{D\Delta (D+y)}dm(x)
$$
But I am stuck on how to show that
$$
\int_{D\Delta (D+y)}dm(x)=\int_\mathbb{R} |\chi_D(x)-\chi_{D+y}(x)|dm(x) \ge 0?
$$

Moreover, after we have
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} |\chi_D(x)-\chi_{D+y}(x)|dm(x)=0
$$

How do we get
$$
\chi_D(x)=\chi_{D+y}(x).  \, a.e.?
$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the $\Delta$ operator here?

Comment: The fact that the Lebesgue integral evaluates to zero implies that the integrated function is zero a.e. (there's actually a proof here at Math SE, so you can find it if you want). This is exactly how you get from the last integral to the desired equation.

Comment: And by the way, what is the nature of $D$? Is it countable/uncountable?

Comment: $f \ge 0, \int fd\mu=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e. This is a very basic result in measure theory.

Comment: @o.spectrum Here is the set difference $A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$

Comment: @o.spectrum I think $D$ can be uncountable... Does it matter?

Comment: @Hermi it quite didn't, just I wanted to understand what $D+y$ means, and how to write it in terms of sets, so that was kind-of more of an idle question :)

Comment: @o.spectrum Just fix $y$, and $E+y:=\{e+y: e\in E\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that by the $\Delta$ operator you mean the symmetric difference and that for a given set $D=\{d_1, d_2, \ldots,d_n,\ldots\}$ by $D+y$ you mean $\{d_1+y, d_2+y,\ldots,d_n+y,\ldots\}$. Let us also assume that $m(D)<+\infty$ and $m(D+y)<+\infty$.

Let us rewrite your integral a bit:
\begin{align}
0&= \int_{D\Delta D+y}\;m(dx)\\
&=\int_{(D\setminus D+y)\cup (D+y \setminus D)}\;m(dx)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{(D\setminus D+y)\cup (D+y \setminus D)}(x)\;m(dx)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{D\setminus D+y}(x) \oplus\chi_{D+y\setminus D}(x)\;m(dx)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\chi_{D\setminus D+y}(x)| \oplus|\chi_{D+y\setminus D}(x)|\;m(dx)\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\chi_{D\setminus D+y}(x) -\chi_{D+y\setminus D}(x)|\;m(dx)\;\text{ (by the properties of xor)}\\
&=  \int_{\mathbb{R}}|(\chi_{D\setminus D+y}(x)+\chi_{D\cap D+y}(x)) -(\chi_{D+y\setminus D}(x)+\chi_{D+y\cap D}(x))|\;m(dx)\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}|(\chi_{(D\cap (D+y)^c)\cup(D\cap D+y)}(x)) -(\chi_{(D+y\cap D^c)\cup(D+y\cap D)}(x))|\;m(dx)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\chi_D(x)-\chi_{D+y}(x)|\;m(dx)
\end{align}
Since we have that by given the measure over the symmetric difference is zero, we have that the last integral evaluates exactly to zero as well. After that you can apply the fact mentioned by @geetha290krm and get that $|\chi_D(x)-\chi_{D+y}(x)|=0$ a.e., and further that
$$
\chi_D(x)=\chi_{D+y}(x)\; \text{ a.e.}
$$

Comment: Thanks. But I think $|\chi_D(x)-\chi_{D+y}(x)|=\chi_{D\Delta (D+y)}(x)$, right?

Comment: Also, can we say that $\chi_D(x)=\chi_D(x+y)$ a.e.?

Comment: No, in fact you cannot make such a direct equality there in general. It's rather $\chi_{D\Delta D+y}(x)=\chi_{D}(x)\oplus \chi_{D+y}(x)$ in general case scenario. This is only the assumption of yours that $m(D\Delta D+y)=0$ that allows to state us that $\chi_{D\Delta D+y}(x)=|\chi_{D}(x)-\chi_{D+y}(x)|$ in this very case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $\chi_D(x+y)$, if $y$ in this context is just some scalar then yes, because in fact it's not the variable, we evaluate the indicator function over, that matters but rather its domain. For me at least, $\chi_D(x)=\chi_D(x+y)$ a.e. doesn't really make any practical sense, since, well, $\chi_D$ is just the very same indicator for both LHS and RHS here.

Comment: Ok, because I try to understand the answer in this question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103473/revisiting-a-lebesgue-measure-question-involving-a-dense-subset-of-r-translates?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: But I discuss all cases for $x\in A\cap B$, and $ x\in A$ but $x\notin B$,...I can show that $|\chi _A-\chi_B|=\chi_{A\Delta B}$. I am not sure why do you say they are not equal? Can you give me one case that they are not equal?

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457402/symmetric-difference-characteristic-function-lebesgue-norm/3457442#3457442

Comment: Oh, in fact you're right. Just I seem to have made a slip myself, as I was actually relating to measures first, not the indicator functions. Instead of a "$+$" under the integral, we must actually have "$\oplus$" (the xor), and then the direct equality can be drawn.